# How to resolve java.net.SocketException:Connection reset. Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host

Tags: java, email, smtp, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to send an email using an organization's SMTP host.

```
@Autowired
 private JavaMailSender mailSender;
@Autowired
 private VelocityEngine velocityEngine;
@Autowired
 private SimpleMailMessage templateMessage;


public void emailSender(final User user) throws Exception 
{

    SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();

    message.setFrom(templateMessage.getFrom());
    message.setTo(user.getEmail());
    System.out.println(user.getEmail());

    message.setSubject(templateMessage.getSubject());
    System.out.println(templateMessage.getSubject());

    message.setText("Your new password is "+ user.getPassword());
    System.out.println("Your new password is "+ user.getPassword());

    mailSender.send(message);
    System.out.println(message);

}
```

**Configuration**

```
 <bean id="emailSender" class="org.iti.utility.SendEmail">
        <property name="mailSender" ref="mailSender" /> 
        <property name="velocityEngine" ref="velocityEngine" /> 
        <property name="templateMessage" ref="templateMessage" /> 
    </bean> 

  <bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
        <property name="host" value="10.6.12.229" />
        <property name="port" value="389" /> 
        <property name="javaMailProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop> 
                <prop key="mail.smtps.starttls.enable">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtps</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>      
     <bean id="velocityEngine" class="org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean">
        <property name="velocityProperties">
        <value>resource.loader=class class.resource.loader.class=org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader</value> 
        </property>
    </bean>  
    <bean id="templateMessage" class="org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage">
        <property name="from" value="noreply@scrumtracker.com" /> 
        <property name="subject" value="Scrum Tracker Login Details" /> 
    </bean>
```

**Stack Trace**

```
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "10.6.12.229", port 389, isSSL true
Nov 23, 2015 4:16:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path [/OLPV] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: 10.6.12.229, port: 389;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketException: Connection reset. Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: 10.6.12.229, port: 389;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketException: Connection reset; message exceptions (1) are:
Failed message 1: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: 10.6.12.229, port: 389;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketException: Connection reset] with root cause
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java:548)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:352)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:233)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1938)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:642)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:389)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:306)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:296)
    at org.iti.utility.SendEmail.emailSender(SendEmail.java:188)
    at org.iti.controller.UserController.forgetPassword(UserController.java:101)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:201)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:163)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:556)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:401)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:242)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:267)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:245)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:260)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I see that it is trying to conncet to the host and host "10.6.12.229", port 389, isSSL true. But I'm getting the above exception. Any idea on this? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use some mail application such as thunderbird with this settings and send email. I think problem is in configuration.

Comment: I have to use my organizations mail application and I can't use thunderbird

Comment: So what a problem. Can You use this mail server from your mail application?

Comment: which server you talking about??

Comment: Server that You try t uuse for sending mails from Java. Can You send mail from your mail app by this server with this settings?

Answer (score 0):

1) Are your **SURE** you have configured correct port?

Port 389 is intended for use by LDAP.

SMTP typically uses ports: 25 (smtp), 465(smtps) and 587 (msa/submission)

Your configuration:

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
        <property name="port" value="389" />
```

2) Do you get SMTP greeting message?

Use `telnet host-name port-number` to test it. You should get SMTP greeting unless the service uses SMTPS (SSL encryption started **before** SMTP level communication).

Comment: A  Could you please tell what are the possible changes required to solve that exception?

Comment: A, I can't use telnet,i am unable to use telnet to test host-name and port-number.